# Restructuring sections in responsive design with only CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

How would you go about completely restructuring sections of a webpage in mobile vs. desktop layouts?
I want to achieve a layout similar to the following:

```
Desktop:
--------
Primary         |   Complementary 1
                |   Complementary 2
Secondary       |

Mobile:
-------
Complementary 1
Primary
Complementary 2
Secondary
```

Note: The separation in Desktop should be one straight line, Complementaries have a fixed width with max-width, Primary/Secondary fill the rest of the page. Additionally, the height of all sections are different. Also notice the interleaved order in mobile.
All this prevents me from using a simple flexbox approach using order and row/column to achieve this.

They way I see it: The clear horizontal separation in desktop is only really viable by putting both columns in a div - but that inherently prevents the mobile layout.
If there's a way to completely ignore a wrapping div through css it might be possible, but I've never head of that.

Any ideas are appreciated - using Javascript this is possible of course but if there's a clever, more or less CSS-only solution I'd greatly prefer that.

Comment: Just get a responsive css grid (or a whole UI framework) and learn the semantics on how to use it and make your life easier in general. Like [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), [foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html), or even good 'ol just plain [grid](https://css-tricks.com/look-ma-no-media-queries-responsive-layouts-using-css-grid/). Either way this is a really broad question.

Comment: A whole framework for this website would be unwise, since half of the CSS code has to be custom made (or else I'd trade with DOM complexity to get all those specialities done). 
Anyway, forgot about grids (last website 2 years ago). Seems they also support order, so I think that might be possible... Thanks!

Comment: As said below, grids seem to have the problem that you have to explicitly state which one of Primary or Complementary1 is larger - unless there's a way around that

Comment: Another path I'm going to research now: Back to flexbox, but force a column-break. Vertical flexbox, force two columns (only vague idea how that could be possible with basis/grow/etc., maybe it's not possible since height can grow indefinitely) and then they can easily distribute the space vertically.
On mobile then simple flexbox with order on items.

Comment: That has another limitation though, I wouldn't be able to do a column-span - that is not part of the question, but I planned to have another section above that that is either spanning both columns or is in the left. Easy with grid, hard with flexbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, this can be achieved relatively easily using the CSS declaration, `display: grid` and setting it to a media query of the desired size.

If you first structure the content in the way you wish to display it as a single column (i.e. `Complementary 1`, `Primary`, ...) you can then simply create a media query with a `min-width` (whatever you want the minimum width to be) and then use a grid to set out the content accordingly. For example:

```css
/* Set grid layout for screens larger than 700px only */
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 2em;
  }
  
  /* place sections into relevant columns/rows */
  .grid main {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-start: 1;
  }
  
  .grid section {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-start: 3;
  }
  
  .grid aside {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-row-start: 1;
  }
  
  .grid main + aside {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-row-start: 2;
  }
  
  /* Add a rule between the aside and the main content */
  aside {
    padding-left: 2em;
    border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="grid">
  <aside>
    <p>Complementary 1</p>
  </aside>
  
  <main>
    <h1>Main content</h1>
    <p>Your main content can go here...</p>
  </main>
  
  <aside>
    <p>Complementary 2</p>
  </aside>
  
  <section>
    <h1>Secondary content</h1>
    <p>Your secondary content can go here...</p>
  </section>
</section>
```

One thing to note is that you seemed to have your 'secondary content' start below the 'complementary' content in the example above. I am not sure if this was just a formatting error - if this was not intentional, you can adjust the `grid-row-start` as appropriate.

**EDIT:**

You can make the columns size-independent using `display: contain`, but be warned - support for this is [pretty terrible](https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20content)! If accessibility is not a particular concern, this should suffice.

If accessibility *is* a concern, you can achieve the below relatively easily using JavaScript, and simply wrapping the `main` and `section` elements in a div, and the `asides` in another div depending on the screen size. This would get around the poor support for `display: contain` which simply makes the element in question `invisible` anyway (so removing a wrapping `<div>` using JavaScript would effectively do the same thing as setting it to `display: contain` anyway).

Hopefully that gives you a direction to go in.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid > div {
  display: contents;
}

.grid aside {
  order: 1;
}

.grid aside + aside {
  order: 3;
}

.grid main {
  order: 2;
}

.grid section {
  order: 4;
}

.grid main,
.grid section,
.grid aside {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Set grid layout for screens larger than 700px only */
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 2em;
  }
  
  .grid > div {
    display: block;
  }
  
  /* Add a rule between the aside and the main content */
  .grid > div + div {
    padding-left: 2em;
    border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  }
  
  /* Set order back to 0 */
  .grid section,
  .grid main,
  .grid aside {
    order: unset;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="grid">
  <div>
    <main>
      <h1>Main content</h1>
      <p>Your main content can go here...</p>
    </main>

    <section>
      <h1>Secondary content</h1>
      <p>Your secondary content can go here...</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <aside>
      <p>Complementary 1</p>
      <p>Complementary 1</p>
      <p>Complementary 1</p>
      <p>Complementary 1</p>
      <p>Complementary 1</p>
      <p>Complementary 1</p>
    </aside>

    <aside>
      <p>Complementary 2</p>
    </aside>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That was just to say they can be different heights - I'm able to modify your code so that they can be next to each other, however that has one limitation. Generally, aside1 is larger than main, but not always - but afaik with grids I'd have to choose which one is larger beforehand. Here are some areas to illustrate:

If main is larger than aside1 I'd need:
"main aside1""main aside2""section aside2"
If main is smaller than aside1 I'd need:
"main aside1""section aside1""section aside2"

Comment: ^^ In short, unless the problem of independant heights can be solved, this will need code again to somehow sort that out (and the height of main can change, expand/hide sort of type, so that'll get messy)

Comment: OK - if you check my most recent edit, hopefully that gives you a better direction to go in :)

Comment: Right, I assume without any kind of javascript there's no way.
display: content; is exactly what I wanted when considering the column approach, accessibility isn't even a problem since the columns are just divs - but since support even then is less than 90%, I'll go for javascript. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wait wait I think I have an idea - might not work, but what about the grid in desktop using areas "main side" and then assign more than one section to either of them? Assuming they stay in their initial order and just expand as in normal divs, that is essentially removing the necissity for column divs. Will try

Comment: ^^ That path is also problematic, you can't control the flow within cells, they will simply overlap - no way I found to make them append like a flexbox...